# Can I inject javascript code from the address bar into a flash video

Tags: javascript, flash

With regular HTML it's possible to change the look of the page and  make new cookies using javascript simply by typing it into the address bar and hitting Enter on keyboard.But what about flash videos.Is there a way to preform some action on the video on the page using javascript in the address bar?

Comment: Thank you both.But my question was can users access flash content through the javascript in broswer and if they can how to stop them?

Comment: What do you mean by flash content? JavaScript can manipulate the DOM so if you mean the `<object>` HTML tag that holds the Flash plugin, than yes JS injection can be used to fiddle with that. And no, you probably cannot prevent that.

Comment: I mean this,there is an api to control the page and javascript from flash,but is there a way that an user can just type som js code in the address bar and mess the .swf file?

Comment: That's up to browser security, it shouldn't concern you directly unless it's server side related. Even if that is not possible, a user can inject JavaScript directly in your files, he doesn't have to bother to write in the URL bar. FireBug for Firefox allows you to run JavaScript code on a loaded site. Opera Dragonfly the same. There are others as well.

Comment: They cannot mess with the code inside the SWF file directly unless you are listening for JS callbacks inside your AS code and not sanitizing input properly (if the case).

Comment: Ok thank you that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I've updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood your question, I would advise that the last thing you would want to do is allow Javascript entered into your address bar to have any control over your page content.

Doing so allows users to abuse your pages and is also a security threat.

If you can avoid passing Javascript via the address bar, it is entirely possible for Javascript to 'control' flash objects on the page. Check this out:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

And also this thread too:

[Controlling a Flash Player using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328194/controlling-a-flash-player-using-javascript)

Comment: +1 voluntarily giving users access to running js from a url is just asking, nay, *pleading* for bad things to happen.

Comment: ...Users can already execute arbitrary javascript. If your flash application communicates with javascript, the client can make arbitrary commands against it. There's no preventing that.

Comment: This and the first comment are miss leading, it's always possible for the client to execute arbitrary JavaScript. It's client side code, the client has free rain on it and can manipulate it however they like. The only point were it becomes a security issue is if you store client JavaScript code on the server and then output it somewhere, this can lead to cookie theft, it's for this reason things like hotmail filter out script code. And as a note, you should never except any data from the client without sanitizing it. Don't assume the client JavaScript code you wrote will be used as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that.
AS3 has the ExternalInterface class that deals with calling JavaScript functions from Flash.

You can both call JavaScript functions and get results returned by JavaScript functions directly from Flash.

All you need is read this: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

**Added after comments:**
User is asking if JavaScript placed in address bar can "mess with swf" file.
JavaScript can only mess with SWF execution of its AS code if it contains callbacks that get data from JavaScript which are not properly sanitized.
JavaScript directly in address bar is less of a wary because using various addons, software etc (Firebug, Dragonfly) you can write as much JavaScript as you want and execute it as if it was part of that site (client side execution).