# Flash Video Pause/Resume When the Window is Minimized or Tab is Changed

Tags: javascript, flash, video, minimize

I achieve that function for default HTML video with these code:

```
window.addEventListener("focus", aaa);
window.addEventListener("blur", bbb);
function aaa(){
document.getElementById('player').play();    }
function bbb(){
document.getElementById('player').pause();}
```

But I have a code now including a flash player in which my video is shown. The code above is not working for flash player? Is there a way that I can pause video when the browser tab is changed or the window is minimized?
Here is my code (pause function is not working, it is executed as usual-as I did nothing)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google" value="notranslate" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title></title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand|Actor' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="skins/overlay/techsmith-smart-player.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>
html, body {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tscVideoContent">
    <img width="32px" height="32px" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -16px 0 0 -16px"
         src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhIAAgAPMAAAAAAP///zg4OAA==">
</div>

<script src="scripts/config_xml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (window) {
        function setup(TSC) {
            TSC.playerConfiguration.setFlashPlayerSwf("DataModel_controller.swf");
             TSC.playerConfiguration.addMediaSrc("DataModel.mp4");
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setXMPSrc("DataModel_config.xml");
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setAutoHideControls(true);
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setBackgroundColor("#000000");
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setCaptionsEnabled(false);
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setSidebarEnabled(false);
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setAutoPlayMedia(false);
      TSC.playerConfiguration.setPosterImageSrc("DataModel_First_Frame.png");
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setIsSearchable(true);
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setEndActionType("stop");
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setEndActionParam("true");
             TSC.playerConfiguration.setAllowRewind(-1);
             TSC.localizationStrings.setLanguage(TSC.languageCodes.ENGLISH);
             ;
             TSC.mediaPlayer.init("#tscVideoContent");
        }

        function loadScript(e,t){if(!e||!(typeof e==="string")){return}var n=document.createElement("script");if(typeof document.attachEvent==="object"){n.onreadystatechange=function(){if(n.readyState==="complete"||n.readyState==="loaded"){if(t){t()}}}}else{n.onload=function(){if(t){t()}}}n.src=e;document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(n)}

        loadScript('scripts/techsmith-smart-player.min.js', function() {
            setup(window["TSC"]);
        });
    }(window));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Draken Don't insult the OP, Flash is still a good option for protected DRM content.

Comment: It wasn't an insult, merely just shocked. Apologies if any offence caused

Comment: Being more constructive, have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328194/controlling-a-flash-player-using-javascript